Displaying two elements in the same coordinate in QGIS
In QGIS I have two elements in the same coordinate and I believe the software is recognizing them as only one point. Is there a way for me to visually display in the map the presence of more than one element at that point?


Add the data twice to the table of contents.  Symbolize the top set a data with a point.  Symbolize the data that is lower in the stack as a large size point of a different color or shape.  Rename the second element so that your legend is clear what the second element is and why it is different that the points above.

You should use the point cluster classification.
https://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/lesson/symbology-22/detail/173/?q=3.15

the  "Point Displacement" renderer could also be used depending on how you want to visualise superposed point
